# Save Two forms at the same time using jquery or ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm planning on saving 2 forms but the 1st form is where I get the Foreign key for the Second form.

This is my Attempt to save this Using Javascript:

```
$("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#workForm').submit();
        $('#contForm').submit();
    });
```

But it errors on Contact Form Submit in the control because the ID of Worker Form is still null while saving the contact form that is its Foreign Key

How can I Handle This using Jquery and Javascript and Ajax?

I also Tried this method:

```
$("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();


        if (Id != 0) {
            $('#workForm').submit();
            $('#contForm').submit();
        } else {
           $('#workForm').submit(); }
    });
```

But it only goes at Else because the ID is null

I hope someone can help me here

Worker Address is the WorkForm Worker Contact is the ContForm

I want to save them both when they populate all the textbox

[image]

Comment: you cant save two forms on a single click..unless you use ajax

Comment: Why dont you try AJAX call and send all the information at once and save the data one after another?

Comment: Ohh Ajax . @ubercooluk can you show it?

Comment: You could merge the inputs from the second form into hidden inputs in the first one and send those

Comment: Since you're using MVC, you can use the Ajax helpers from MVC, this Article might be interesting: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429164/Html-BeginForm-vs-Ajax-BeginForm-in-MVC3

Answer (score 0):

You need to post both forms using .ajax. Serialize the data from both forms and then post to your server script.

```
$("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Serialize the form data
  var formOne$ = $('#workForm').serialize();
  var formTwo$ = $('#contForm').serialize();

  $.ajax( { url : "YOURURL", type: 'post', data : { formOne : formOne$ , formTwo : formTwo$ }, 
    success : function( responseText ){
        //Forms were submitted
    },
    error : function( e ){
        alert( ' Error : ' + e.statusText );
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Sir Thank you but can i ask what will i include in that "YOURURL" ? 

Thanks , I think im on the right track with your answer

Comment: YOURURL is the location of the server script that will process the data. Eg '/process_forms'.

Comment: You'll also have to parse the serialized form data into array's in your server script so that you can access the data you require.

Comment: Sir i tried this method and i think its working but how could i submit the forms ? Thanks!

Comment: This function is submitting the data from both forms via ajax meaning the browser will not navigate away from the page. You can make changes to the DOM inside the success function e.g replace the forms with a message telling the user that the forms have been submitted - $('#formWrapper').html('The data has been submitted')

Comment: How can i resolve it sir. . When i save the workForm, the page refreshes and the value of the cont form will gone?

Comment: I dont know what should i use in url, can you help me pinpoint it ?? Thanks :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34148/discussion-between-user2586583-and-enrique-gil)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use ajax because

```
$('#contForm').submit();
```

will never be run as the page will be unloaded by the first call:

```
 $('#workForm').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the first form using `ajaxSubmit()` and on its success, submit the second form.

```
$("#btnSave").click(function() {
    $('#workForm').ajaxSubmit({
        forceSync: true,
        error: function(errorDetails) {
            //Error Handling
        },
        success: function(successData) {
            $('#contForm').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: in this method. the Add button has no function

Comment: I did not understand you. The `ajaxSubmit()` will be called when you click on the add button. (See edit)

Comment: also, make sure your `button` has the attribute `type = "button"`

Comment: the error is Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ajaxSubmit'

Comment: You have to include `jquery.form.js`. http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/form

Comment: can i see it in JsFiddle sir? 

an Example maybe?

Comment: There was a typo in my code. I missed a '{' in the ajaxSubmit() method. I have edited it. Argument to success and error functions are not compulsory. You can choose to remove them.

Comment: So can i leave it blank or get it like this `success: function() {
            $('#contForm').submit();` ?? Thanks alot :D